# Problem with constraints in custom CollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

Faced a problem. The contents of the cell are not based on the borders of the cell but on the screen. I set constraints for objects in a custom cell:

```
override func setupViews() {

    addSubview(staffLabel)
    addSubview(shiftCollectionView)


    staffLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
    staffLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
    staffLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    staffLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    shiftCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    shiftCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    shiftCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: staffLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    shiftCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

But in the simulator I get [image: this.]

As you can see my CollectionView has safeArea constants. But the contents of its cells are not. (By the way, the header is displayed correctly for some reason). Code for cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: schedulesCellIdentifire, for: indexPath) as! SchedulesCell
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: footerCollectionViewCellIdentifire, for: indexPath) as! CalendarFooterLineCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Code for header:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerCollectionViewCellIdentifire, for: indexPath)
}
```

How can I use SafeArea in my custom collectionViewCell or how else to fix it?

I want the contents of the cells to appear within the borders of the CollectionView. Now the contents of the cells are displayed within the boundaries of the screen, this is partially hidden (((

I apologize. I did not describe my idea clearly enough. I want it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jjm5.png)

But for this effect, I manually set the constraint from the leftAnchor of the screen to 44 points. This is not cool because I use this CollectionView on another ViewController and indentation of 44 points is not needed there ((

staffLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 44).isActive = true

I have a problem displaying the Staff column. It should be displayed either in borders in collectionView (collectionView is set with SafeArea in mind), but this does not happen automatically.

Or do I need a way to define SafeArea boundaries in a custom CollectionViewCell class.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Off topic: If all those cells are meant to be tappable, it's really bad UX because the tap areas are so close together.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Are you concerned about cells being cut off by the safe area? If so, what would you prefer? Do you want to show cells over the safe area?

Comment: I want the contents of the cells to appear within the borders of the CollectionView. Now the contents of the cells are displayed within the boundaries of the screen, this is partially hidden (((

Comment: @Viktor - it's not clear what you mean... Collection Views are designed to scroll when you have more cells than will fit in the frame. Are you trying to fit 31 columns "days" across the screen? If so, those will be **very** narrow columns - I doubt you could read the tiny text that would be needed.

Comment: I apologize. I did not describe my idea clearly enough. I added a question

Comment: @Viktor - ok, we still need a bit more detail. Is your grid made up of multiple collectionViews? Or is it just one? Are the "staff cells" supplementary views? Is the actual frame of your collectionView laying out correctly, but the "staff cells" extend outside its bounds? Does everything lay out correctly on a device *without* the notch safe-area (or when rotated to portrait orientation)? Can you reduce this to a simple example - see [mcve]?

Comment: I use several CollectionView nested in each other. The main CollectionView is constrain to Safe Area. In the hedere of the first section is a CollectionView with calendar dates.

Comment: The cells of the main CollectionView are installed from a custom class and contain StaffLabel and CollectionView for the shift type. 
These custom cells are not tied to the borders of the container = main CollectionView.